# How to call a function before isotope starts re-layout transition?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, jquery-isotope

I've got a galery which I want to be filterable with isotope. The elements I want to transition don't have a 'definitive' size but the size rather depends on the position in the grid. The grid looks something like this:

```
 ———————————————-———————————————
|               |               |
|               |               |
 ———————————————-———————————————
|         |           |         |
|         |           |         |
 —————————-———————————-—————————
|               |               |
|               |               |
 ———————————————-———————————————
|         |           |         |
|         |           |         |
 —————————-———————————-—————————
```

It has two alternating row patterns. After a filter is applied the grid should still have the same layout pattern (just with fewer elements of course). For example an element wich was at the 3rd position (1st position in the 2nd row) could now be at the 1st position in the 1st row and therefore has a new size. To achieve this layout I have 5 classes ('tile-1' to 'tile-5') which all have specific styles applied to them for the correct with and margin.

My problem now is that I don't know how to apply the correct classes before isotope does the layout when a filter is applied. I didn't find any `beforeLayout()` function or something similar. I tried to use the jQuery callback function wich is called on an animation start like this:

```
$filters.on('click', '.filter', function() {
    var filterVal = $(this).attr('data-filter');
    $galery.isotope({
        filter: filterVal,
        animationEngine: 'jquery',
        animationOptions: {
            start: function() {
                //code that applies correct tile classes
            }
        }
    });
}
```

But somehow this doesn't work either because the function doesn't even get called even though I force the animationEngine to be `'jquery'`. I'm anyway not sure if this would work since I believe isotope does it's internal layouting before it calls the jQuery animation.

Any help welcome!

Comment: I'm not familiar with isotope, but have you tried using 'gallery' rather than 'galery'?

Comment: @Kvothe Uh that's my bad english spelling but has nothing to do with isotope. Thats just a regular js variable I defined above wich holds a jQuery object.

Comment: Ah right, that kind of thing is hard to judge without the rest of the code, can you provide more/all code?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I realised my jsfiddle looked weird in Firefox because of the padding I'd set, fixed now.

This might help, see: http://jsfiddle.net/6st8N/4/

I assume your HTML looks something like this at first... `wide-2`, `wide-3` define the width (if your code is different please supply an example of it).

```
<div id="filters" class="button-group">
  <button data-filter="*">show all</button>
  <button data-filter=".metal">metal</button>
  <button data-filter=".non-metal">non-metal</button>
</div>


<div id="grid">
    <div class="grid-item wide-3 metal">
        <div class="grid-item-inner">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item wide-3 non-metal">
        <div class="grid-item-inner">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item wide-2 metal">
        <div class="grid-item-inner">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item wide-2 non-metal">
        <div class="grid-item-inner">4</div>
    </div>
        <div class="grid-item wide-2 non-metal">
        <div class="grid-item-inner">5</div>
    </div>

    ...
```

After a filter is clicked, you remove all current classes that relate to width and then loop through each matching grid-item and reassign the classes...

```
$('#filters').on( 'click', 'button', function() {
    var filterValue = $(this).attr('data-filter');

    var newItemCounter = 1;

    $('#grid').children(filterValue).each(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('wide-2');
        $(this).removeClass('wide-3');

        if((newItemCounter + 4)%5 == 0 || (newItemCounter +3)%5 == 0) {
            // 1st or second in pattern of 5
            $(this).addClass('wide-3');
        }

        else {
            // 3rd, 4th or 5th in pattern of 5
            $(this).addClass('wide-2');
        }

        newItemCounter++;

    })

    $container.isotope({ filter: filterValue });

});
```